# TABLEAU: How to display grouped regions on map

Tags: sql, inner-join, tableau-api

I would like to display regions based on customized groupings. 
Some regions include groups of states while some include groups of countries. My primary data source only contains information about the region (which is not recognized by the map feature).

I have separate sheets that I use to map the regions to the corresponding states/countries. I tried creating relationships between the sheets. It only displayed either regions in all the state sheet or in the country sheet. How do I make it so that it can display both to show all the regions?

Primary Source Data Example

[Name] [Salary] [Region]

 xx         xx          SW 

 xx         xx          Europe

Country Sheet

[Region] [Country] 

Europe     Italy 

Europe     France

State Sheet Example:

[Region] [State]

SW        California

Comment: Good question, I don't know and I'm very curious to find out if that is even possible. Even grouping data (like group many states) doesn't work (it shows only the first state of the group). All that on the map display of course (shouldn't be hard to make other kinds of charts)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to tackle this problem. You can find more information here:

http://community.tableausoftware.com/ideas/1492

Another simple way to solve it would be to convert all region data to lowest hierarchy, here it is state; and map on Tableau. We will color and label it using Region to show groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free open source tool for QuantumGIS that automates this for you.. You can get the geography files for country for free load them into QuantumGIS, and then use a 2 column CSV file to automate creating the regions.. Then you can load them into Tab. http://cmapsanalytics.com/customregions.html